# Error making auto-update zip cx_freeze and esky 'Freezer' object has no attribute 'createLibraryZip'

Tags: python, cx-freeze, esky

I'm trying to create auto-update zip using esky, I was able to create msi but when I try to make the auto-update zip i get an error referring that 'Freezer' object has no attribute 'createLibraryZip'

I'm developing this on a Windows 10 machine using python 3.5 from git bash.

I created my setup script based on this tutorial
https://fernandofreitasalves.com/how-to-create-an-application-with-auto-update-using-python-and-esky/

`python setup.py bdist_esky`

```
...
copying C:\c\Users\Ezequiel\.virtualenvs\appcon\lib\site-packages\win32\win32wnet.pyd -> dist\appcon-1.1.0.win32\appcon-1.1.0.win32\lib\win32wnet.pyd
copying logging.ini -> dist\appcon-1.1.0.win32\appcon-1.1.0.win32
copying config.ini -> dist\appcon-1.1.0.win32\appcon-1.1.0.win32
copying icon.png -> dist\appcon-1.1.0.win32\appcon-1.1.0.win32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 40, in <module>
    base=base,
  File "C:\c\Users\Ezequiel\.virtualenvs\appcon\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\users\ezequiel\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\users\ezequiel\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\users\ezequiel\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\c\Users\Ezequiel\.virtualenvs\appcon\lib\site-packages\esky\bdist_esky\__init__.py", line 312, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\c\Users\Ezequiel\.virtualenvs\appcon\lib\site-packages\esky\bdist_esky\__init__.py", line 320, in _run
    self._run_freeze_scripts()
  File "C:\c\Users\Ezequiel\.virtualenvs\appcon\lib\site-packages\esky\bdist_esky\__init__.py", line 345, in _run_freeze_scripts
    self.freezer_module.freeze(self)
  File "C:\c\Users\Ezequiel\.virtualenvs\appcon\lib\site-packages\esky\bdist_esky\f_cxfreeze.py", line 81, in freeze
    if f.createLibraryZip:
AttributeError: 'Freezer' object has no attribute 'createLibraryZip'
```

this is my setup.py script

```
#setup.py
import sys, os
import esky.bdist_esky
from esky.bdist_esky import Executable as Executable_Esky
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Ezequiel\.virtualenvs\appdesktop\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Ezequiel\.virtualenvs\appdesktop\tcl\tk8.6'

__version__ = "1.1.0"
include_files = ['logging.ini', 'config.ini', 'icon.png']

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

setup(
    name = "appcon",
    description='Colaboration App',
    version = __version__,
    options = {
        'build_exe': {
            'packages': ["os", "idna", "appactions", "customfilehandler", "errno", "ui", "wx","threading","time","logging","configparser","requests","json","base64","pyodbc"],
            'excludes': ["tkinter"],
            'include_files': include_files,
            'include_msvcr': True,
        },
        'bdist_esky': {
            'freezer_module': 'cx_freeze',
        }
    },
    data_files = include_files,
    scripts = [
        Executable_Esky(
            'main.py',
            gui_only = True,
            # icon = "icon.png"
            ),
    ],
    executables = [Executable('main.py',
                        base=base,
                        # shortcutName="App Connector",
                        # shortcutDir="DesktopFolder",
                    )]
    )
```

I realize that error is allways pointing to "executables" on the last parameter, if I uncomment "shortcutName" error is marked on that line.

I was googling error with no results, I don´t know ir there is something else i must install...

Comment: I am suffering from same issue how you solve this problem?

Comment: Any hint of alternatives for the auto-update feature?

Answer (score 1):

If you have upgraded to cx_Freeze 5 or higher then createLibraryZip is gone as it always happens. That was an option in earlier versions of cx_Freeze.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed I have `cx-Freeze==5.1.1, esky==0.9.9`
I'm new on this, how is supposed i can workaround this?
I'm running `python setup.py bdist_esky`

Comment: If I run with with bdist_msi it works and make the msi, but I don't get how to combine with esky

Comment: I am not familiar with esky so can't help there, unfortunately!

Answer (score 1):

The newest verion of cx_freeze that support esky is 4.3.4 ,unfortunately the esky has stop upgrading for several years...